# EPPLUS categories in reverse order

Tags: charts, epplus

I created the bar chart using the code below.
But I need to make 2 modifications and I'm not finding how to do it.

```
            var chart = (ExcelBarChart)ws.Drawings.AddChart("barChart", eChartType.BarClustered);
            chart.SetSize(1000, 500);
            chart.SetPosition(10, 225);
            chart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Bottom;
            chart.YAxis.MaxValue = 4;
```

1) I need to remove the rounded border, I need straight.
2) I need to change the orientation of the categories, as shown in the image below.

[Image of the graph is, and how I wish it to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsaVr.jpg)

If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close!

You can use `chart.RoundedCorners = false;` to remove the rounded edges.

Use `chart.XAxis.Orientation = eAxisOrientation.MaxMin;` to change the category orientation.

Using my own data, your code produced this:
[image]

After adding this code

```
chart.RoundedCorners = false;
chart.XAxis.Orientation = eAxisOrientation.MaxMin;
```

You get this:
[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly.
Thanks a lot for the help.